# .NET SQL Server DataAdapter returning the wrong field type?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, dataadapter

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 targeting the .Net 2.0 framework, connecting to SQL Server 2008. Have a field called `Box_no` of type `varchar(50)` in a table. The field's contents are mostly numbers, some are empty. Nulls allowed but there aren't any.

Here's the code which queries this table and displays in a grid (the else omitted):

```
DataTable dtRaw = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sdaRaw;
if (rbRestrictCount.Checked)
{
   sdaRaw = new SqlDataAdapter("Select top 50 * from MyTable where ID >= \'" + numericUpDown1.Value + "\' Order By ID",
                                                       Properties.Settings.Default.ConnStr);
};
sdaRaw.Fill(dtRaw);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRaw;
```

Pretty straighforward. The trouble is according the vaue of ID (i.e. where the search starts from), the field `box_no` is sometimes displayed in scientific notation - 2.4e+.... etc.  - other times it displays as text. It's definitely defined as `varchar` in the table but it seems as if the data adapter is attempting to infer a different field type when it creates the DataTable structure. Is there someway to tell it not to do this?

Comment: are your datagridview columns autogenerated or have you manually added them?

Comment: Don't concatenate your sql strings like that, even for numeric fields. There are ways to stuff any string I want in your numericUpDown1 value, and with that I could completely take over your database.

Comment: Also, your sample looks like it will throw an exception is rbRestrictCount is not checked.

Comment: Autogenerated. And Joel thanks for your concern but I know what I'm doing.

Comment: Joel - as I said in the initial post I didn't show the else - if that's all the code was it wouldn't thrown an exception - it wouildn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

try this before assigning it to the data source

```
dtRaw.Columns["box_no"].DataType = typeof(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but have found the issue - the scientific notation is actually in the data itself - it was an import from  an XLS spreadsheet which seems to have caused this on 69K out of 700K records. Thanks